# No sound since I first pressed "mute" on my keyboard

Tags: audio

I have a problem with sound. I once pressed the mute button on my keyboard and since then I couldn't do anything to get the sound back on my headphones (obviously, including pressing mute again).

I tried to go into alsamixer and everything seems okay, except the headphone, which seems like it has no volume at all (and it says: `Item: Headphone [Off, Off]`) and I also can't increase it. As for the rest (master, pcm, surround, center etc) are all okay. My sound card is a HDA Intel, Realtek ALC1200.

```
uname -a:
Linux ... 3.2.0-53-generic-pae #81-Ubuntu SMP Thu Aug 22 21:23:47 UTC 2013 i686 i686 i386 GNU/Linux
```

Any clue?

---

Comment: please do *not* add an answer as part of your question. instead create a new "answer" and mark it as accepted. this way people will know that there is a solution to the problem.

Comment: I know @umläute but I will do that as soon as I am allowed to, since I'm new here. That means 8h or so. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

**Fixed it**: The sound was still muted. Seems like the mute button on my keyboard could only mute sound and could not unmute it. I restored the sound with pavucontrol. You can install with "sudo apt-get install pavucontrol".